# Jersey Test Equivalent to curl request

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey

First trip into the Java web services world.  Trying to write a test for a post request.  The post looks like this in curl:

```
url -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"transaction_zips": ["78732"],"condition": "good"}' http://localhost:8080/PricingService/vin/1GTEC19J37E152026/usedValues
```

I've attempted:

```
@Test
public void testVinPricing200() {
    int status = target.path("PricingService/vin/1GTEC19J37E152026/usedValues").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).
            post(Entity.entity("{\"transaction_zips\": [\"78732\"],\"condition\": \"good\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).getStatus();
    assertEquals(200, status);
}
```

This results in:

```
Failed tests:   testVinPricing200(com.comp.platform.PricingServiceTest): expected:<200> but was:<406>
```

So the question is simple, I'm obviously not posting correctly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know that Jersey is not very verbose, but did you get any error message add all?

Comment: Does the curl return an expected response?

Comment: The curl does return the expected response.  The short return is listed in the question in the third code block

Comment: "short return" is the error return on the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your `curl` request and your `junit` test in your `junit test` you are requesting a response of type `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE`, but your `webservice` is not capable of `responding` via `JSON`.

Http Status code: [406](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

```
The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities
which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in 
the request.
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem.  I thought I had set JSON as the production type in the service, and while I had set the consumption correctly I had not set the production correctly.  Thank-you Sajan.